# Inno Setup: how can I resize the lower pane area?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I resize the bottom area pane of the installer?

[image]

I'd like it to be twice the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower pane are is actually an empty area. So you just need to increase the window height and decrease height of the `OuterNotebook` and shift up the `Bevel`:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure IncreaseFooter(Delta: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.Height := WizardForm.Height + Delta;
  WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height - Delta;
  WizardForm.Bevel.Top := WizardForm.Bevel.Top - Delta;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  IncreaseFooter(ScaleY(46));
end;
```

[image]